# Jqgrid edittype : select editoptions: dataUrl is not called to populate the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to populate one of the columns using select box in jqgrid. Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "./info",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        ajaxSelectOptions:{
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        },
        colNames: ["DeptId", "DeptName", "StuId", "StuName", "StuDoj"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "deptId", hidden:true },
            { name:"deptName", width:90, editable:true, edittype:'select', formatter:'select', editoptions:{
                dataUrl:'./getDepts',
                buildSelect: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                    var s='<select id="dept" name="dept">'
                    $.each(res,function(idx,obj){
                        $('#dept')
                          .append($('<option>', { value : obj.deptId })
                          .text(obj.deptName));
                    }); 
                    return s+"</select>";
                }
            }},
            { name: "studentId", hidden:true },
            { name: "studentName", width: 80,editable:true },
            { name: "studentDoj",width: 90,editable:true }
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        sortname: "empId",
        sortorder: "asc",
        sortable:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: "MyGrid",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "empId",
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        }
    }); 
    $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,view:true,search:true});
```

})

In the editOptions for colModel 'deptName' the dataUrl is not called to populate the select box. The jqgrid is populated using /info resturl which fetches the deptName for a particular student. I want the deptName to be of type select box and its value should be same as deptName fetched using info rest url

Comment: How do you determine that the dataUrl is not called? It can be possible that you have point to a wrong url. Please look into debug console (F12) and see what is happen.

Comment: @TonyTomov Using debug tool I am confirming its not called determined through network tab

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be called, but your data will be newer filled, since you overwrite the success function in ajaxSelectOptions.

In order to get response, please comment the success function or remove it

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "./info",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    ajaxSelectOptions:{
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    ....
});
```

**UPDATE:** With small changes your code is working fine. Here is a [link to your code](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/user1690/)

Note that the formatter does not have option dataUrl. It is only available in in editing.

Comment: removing the success function results in no change. Still the url is not called

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: many thanks. its working I have accepted it as correct answer (y)